# Expandable Listview parent and children wrapped in a single layout individually.

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to have each individual parent and its children appear as if they are a single CardView.  I have it working fine with and lolipop (LP) but anything not running below LP the cards are separated. Is it possible to add a root layout to wrap both the parent and its children individually? I have posted two photos and if you need code I will update my answer.  If it is not possible I am going to have to find another solution.

What the view looks like with devices running Lolipop
[image]

What it looks like on lower versions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up scrapping the CardView and creating a custom shadow that emulates the  CardView giving it the same appearance. As of now I believe it is not possible to create an individual layout for the parent and child.